# How to Apache/mod_rewrite redirect client to specific URL based on client's IP in Drupal?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I have a Apache web server that is published internally (LAN) and externally, the http.conf is as follows:

```
    <VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
    ServerName intradev.xxxx.com
    ServerAlias intradev.xxxx.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/intranet/
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/2014.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/2014.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ca_bundle.crt

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/intranet/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location /user/login/sso>
            AuthType GSSAPI
            AuthName "Login SSO"
            Require valid-user
            GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
            GssapiCredStore ccache:MEMORY:user_ccache
            GssapiUseSessions On
            Session On
            SessionCookieName gssapi_session path=/private;httponly;secure;
    </Location>
    LogLevel debug
```

I am trying to redirect users that hit the web server from LAN to the /user/login/sso directory with:

```
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 172.16. [NC,OR]
            RewriteRule .* https://intranet.xxxx.com/user/login/sso [R=301,L]
```

But as soon as I add this under the  block I get a page cannot be displayed.

If I change the RewriteRule to something like https://www.google.com and hit the web server at https://intranet.xxxx.com on the LAN it redirects me to google OK.

What I want it to do is, for any LAN user hitting the https://intranet.xxx.com path to be redirected to the /user/login/sso first.

Maybe mod_rewrite is not the correct place to do this? Any other suggestions? The intranet is a Drupal powered website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be handled in Drupal? I *think* you can do this with it's core function. Just remove view any content permissions for anonymous users and see if that works. And just leave authenticated users. I think since this is based on PHP auth it probably should be handled with the code/cms.

[image]
https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: I don't think that will work, but you did point me to the right direction of using a drupal module; in my case the Rules module and custom PHP.